# Como fazer essa função retornar somente o valor desejado ao mesmo tempo em que recebe ponteiros como argumento?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, algoritmo-de-busca, return

Estou tentando construir uma função que realize uma busca em um vetor de forma binária, mas quero que ela retorne -1 quando o elemento não for encontrado, e quando o elemento for encontrado ela devolva a posição do elemento no vetor, e a quantidade de comparações necessárias para verificar se o elemento está ou não no vetor.
O que está acontecendo: se eu deixo a função com retorno, ela nunca me dá resposta positiva, mesmo quando o elemento está no vetor. Já tentei deixar ela sem retorno, e nesse caso ela devolve para o endereço comparação o numero de comparações e para o endereço chave a posição da chave, mas fica sem a possibilidade de devolver resultado negativo. Já tentei usar a própria chave como ponteiro para fazer essa função de devolver verdadeiro ou falso, mas nesse caso também só devolve resultado negativo.
Já tentei também deixar com dois retornos, um para o caso de resultado falso e outro para o caso de resultado positivo, e funciona a verificação, mas não devolve a quantidade de comparações.

```
int busca_binaria(int v[], int tamanho, int* chave, int* comparacoes) {

    int meio, inicio = 0, fim = tamanho - 1, posicao_chave, quantidade_comparacoes = 0;

    while (inicio <= fim) {
        meio = (fim + inicio) / 2;
        if (*chave == v[meio]) {
            posicao_chave = meio;
        }
        if (*chave > v[meio]) {
            inicio = meio + 1;
        }
        else {
            fim = meio - 1;
        }
        quantidade_comparacoes++;
    }
    *chave = posicao_chave;
    *comparacoes = quantidade_comparacoes;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja abaixo seu código revisado e comentado que realiza suas exigências quanto ao algoritmo:

```
/**
 * BUSCA BINÁRIA em vetor ordenado
 * @return se o elemento 'chave' for encontrado no vetor, a funcao retorna usa posição, caso contrário é retornado -1
 * @param comparacoes é um ponteiro para uma variavel no escopo em que busca_binaria foi instanciada, e guarda a quantidade 
 * de iterações/comparacoes executadas durante a busca
**/
int busca_binaria(int v[], int tamanho, int* chave, int* comparacoes) {

    int meio, inicio = 0, fim = tamanho - 1;

    *comparacoes = 1; // Usa o próprio ponteiro como contador, ao invés de criar a variável quantidade_comparacoes para isso
                      /* Perceba que ele começa com 1, ao invés de zero, isso porque mesmo no melhor caso (quando o elemento procurado estiver no meio)
                       * ainda assim será necessário ao menos uma comparação para validação da igualdade
                       */

    while (inicio <= fim) {
        meio = (fim + inicio) / 2;
        if (*chave == v[meio]) {
            return meio; // Quando encontrado, retorna um valor não negativo (maior ou igual a 0) indicando a posição do elemento
        }
        if (*chave > v[meio]) {
            inicio = meio + 1;
        }
        else {
            fim = meio - 1;
        }
        (*comparacoes)++; // Incrementando o conteúdo do ponteiro
    }

    return -1;
}
```